# How can I improve my pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation, speech

I've left high school and we don't study English at University and I feel that I haven't learnt to pronounce at all yet. 
What habits or routines can I do to speak better and fluent?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You can do pretty well by listening to the BBC, or another news service that is known to use good English (such as National Public Radio in the US).

Comment: Hi Monica, welcome to EL&U. Visit our help page and find how to ask a question here and what topics are welcome.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about opinions and suggestions.

Comment: @Centaurus: I've just cast my CV as "Too Broad", so that's *three* different reasons already! I think they're all equally valid here on ELU - strictly speaking, I think the same would/should apply if the question had been asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but if I'm honest I'd probably have let it stand there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

As a native English speaker (albeit with a regional accent) I make the following suggestions based on my experiences with learning a little Polish, Japanese and Italian.

The primary way of improving our pronunciation is to mix and speak with the people who speak as we aspire.

Addition free methods that help

- Watch and speak with classical movies such as [My Fair Lady](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Fair_Lady).
- Read poetry aloud. This helps with rhythm, and rhyming poetry helps with pronunciation.
- Sing. Church services are a one place we can sing with other people (meaning no one is actually listening to *us*). One does *not* have to be a believer to go and participate, and many churches display the words on a screen.
- Watch the TV news. This can help with current idioms, the *speed* at which native speakers speak, and variations in pronunciation.
- Listen to the radio. This can help develop your "internal voice".
- Do an online course.
- Join a local English speaking association, such as Toastmasters or similar.

And finally, one that can cost money

- Join a local English class.